# Sending string from Django to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, django

Why did JavaScript crash when I tried to send a variable from Django?

This is my variable (I printed it in the Python console):

```
"Date,Zabbix server
" + "2014-11-15 21:58,23271
" + "2014-11-15 21:59,0
" + "2014-11-15 22:00,0
" + "2014-11-15 22:01,0
" + "2014-11-15 22:02,0
" + "2014-11-15 22:03,0
" + "2014-11-15 22:04,0
" + "2014-11-15 22:05,0
" + "2014-11-15 22:06,0
" + "2014-11-15 22:07,0
"
```

I tried to use it in JavaScript:

```
var values = "{{ values }}";
alert(values)
```

But then it crashed. Why? How can I send this text?

Comment: pelase let us see your code

Comment: do you have an error? What is it?  What means are you transmitting it?  What does your javascript code look like? ..etc

Comment: i don't know what django sent because i cant alert this value

Comment: whan code need? in django? them was very hard, because this string created from many classes

Comment: Can you include your view method via which you are rendering your template.

Comment: `some_values = SomeModel.objects.values('pk', 'some_other_field')`
`json.dumps(list(some_values), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)`

Answer (score 0):

The error is mainly due to the fact django templating engine escape your string, so it won't be interpreted as javascript. You have to tell it not to do that.

Using the *safe* template tag

```
var values = "{{ values|safe }}";
```